# Complex Cypher: Match interconnected questions referencing a result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to write some crazy cypher, any help appreciated.

I have Question Nodes, Answer Relationships and Result Nodes in my graph. Answer relationships have a field called text which can be 'yes' or 'no'.

I want to find all Question Nodes that are linked by 'No' with all their 'yes's going to the same Result Node. Can anyone set me on the right track? All i've got is this meagre starting point at the moment:

MATCH n-[:Answer]->(m:Result {id: "DesiredResultId"}) RETURN n,m

Comment: If I understand, you can have two questions linkes by a relationship [:Anwser{text:"yes"}] ?

Comment: I can see my question's being downvoted, I mean i've got my answer so i'm happy but is there something I should have done for it to be better formed or upvotable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initial recommendation:

```
match (r:result)<-[:answer{text:"yes"}]-(n:question)-[:answer{text:"no"}]-(m:question)-[:answer{text:"yes"}]->(r)
return n, m
```

revised recommendation (after discovering the no value could also be "not sure"):

```
match (r:result)<-[:answer{text:"yes"}]-(n:question)-[a:answer]-(m:question)-[:answer{text:"yes"}]->(r)
where a.text = "no" or a.text = "not sure"
return n, m
```

Comment: Where did "not sure" come from? It is not mentioned in the question or in any comments.

Comment: Hi Sam, Magnus and I were talking on irc.freenode.net/#neo4j. We didn't think he'd reach a result which is why I posted the question, but as you can see he eventually came up with the solution. After he sent it to me on IRC I suggested he post it here to get credit for his work and help others out, and then I mentioned the not sure as an addtional case which he added as the 'revised recommendation'